# Back Button not showing with Stack.Navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to implement a simple navigation but for some reason back button it's not showing up.

My Main Component

```js
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {userToken ? (
          <Stack.Screen name={routesName.App} component={TabNavigator} />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name={routesName.Auth} component={AuthStack} />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Tab Navigation

```js
const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name={routesName.Home} component={HomeStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name={routesName.Settings} component={SettingsStack} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

```js
const HomeStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={routesName.Home}>
      <Stack.Screen name={routesName.Home} component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name={routesName.Details} component={DetailsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

```js
const SettingsStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name={routesName.Settings} component={SettingsScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name={routesName.Profile} component={ProfileScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

No matter what screen i go, app headers always shows "App" as title.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it's because your root stack is always on App regardless of your nested ones. try this in your root stack:

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
```

More info here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headershown

Comment: does anything change when you do this? at least the "App" part is gone right?

Comment: Sorry, it actually worked. I added it in `Stack.Screen` instead of `Stack.Navigator`. Now it is working like a charm, thanks!